# How is x0 register set for arm64 kernel start when ACPI table is used instead of device tree?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, boot, uefi, acpi

The head.S file for arm64 (arch/arm64/kernel/head.S) assumes that the x0 register contains the address of the device tree (dtb, or FDT).
But some systems use ACPI table for handing hardware configuration off to the kernel(for example, I heard N1 SDP from arm uses ACPI tables).
If the system firmware and bootloader uses UEFI and ACPI, does the bootloader still set x0 with dtb too(by inspecting ACPI table maybe)?
Or in this case, is x0 not set by the bootloader and x0 is ultimately not used in kernel during kernel boot and instead UEFI system table -> RSDP -> ACPI tables search and namespace building is used? (by some CONFIG setting for kernel building.)

Comment: I think there is an empty device tree, or one with only a `/chosen` and/or a `/hypervisor` node for Xen.

Comment: @IanAbbott that' a good info. thanks.